# Extra argument "named" in call

Tags: ios, swift

```
   @IBAction func rerollTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    var pickupLines:[String] = [
        "aye babe, you from iraq cause you should babhdad ass up",
        "HBB asdjksja asjd aj iueihieu",
        "Dollar Menu akjshdskjhdksj",
        "askdjkjashkjhd",
        "skajshdkasjhdka"
    ]

     var randomPickupLine = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(pickupLines.count))


    self.pickupLabel.text = UILabel(named: randomPickupLine)
```

I'm attempting to randomize pickup lines and display the random line in a label. When the Re-roll button is tapped the next random pickup line is shown in the label.

It seems the problem is with this last line, it says "Extra argument "named" in call"

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UILabel` doesn't have an init method that takes a name (initWithName: in Objective-C) so that's why that is an "extra argument" (to the `init()` method). Perhaps you were thinking of UIImage?

Also, your `randomPickupLine` is a number (the index), not the string value.

Also, you are trying to assign label (a UI element) to the `text` property of another label (which expects a String)

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, I must have mixed the two up. Would you recommend a way of fixing this?